# Failing to install SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I want to include SwiftyJSON into my Xcode 6.3 project.

When I try to build it get about 40 compiler errors. Most of them are similar to **'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'. Did you mean as! to enforce downcast?**

I followed the tutorial steps:

1. Download SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)
2. Drag and drop the SwiftyJSON.swift to my Xcode project.
3. Accepting the "copy if necessary".
4. Re-build project.

My best guess is that since I'm so new I'm missing some very "obvious" step.

Tutorial used: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

Comment: The framework is in an older version of swift

Comment: did you find a solution for the errors.... or another source that uses Swift 2

Answer (score 1):

You are using Swift 2 but the master version of this framework is for Swift 1.2 (until Swift 2 is out of beta). But you can use the other branch: Download [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7)

EDIT: You actually just need a single file which is right [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/xcode7/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift) (Right click on RAW then "Download linked file"). Then you should just be able to drag the downloaded file from the download folder into your project (select "Copy if necessary") and it should be ready to go. I tried it myself and there was just a single deprecation warning.

EDIT: Oh wow I'm so sorry, I totally missed that you were using XCode 6.3. Of course you can't use the XCode 7 branch. [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift) is the XCode 6.3 version of the file

Comment: It did not help. Following the steps in my original post but for the xcode7 branch resulted in 60 compiler errors. Mainly **Swift compiler error unknown attribute 'available'** but also some other like 'consecutive statements on a line must be followed by a ;'

Comment: @mipmap I'll look into it some more, btw you shouldn't mark my answer as correct when it's not ;)

Comment: @kametrixon Thanks for the help, but that did not work either. I got the same 60 compiler errors as before. I also created a new project and added the file to that (in case I messed up some settings).

Comment: @mipmap Oh wow, so sorry totally missed that you were using 6.3, I edited it again. If it doesn't work like this I cannot help you anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your xcode is not updated to the version expected by the swiftyjson library